# Does the View observe the entities or does it observe the services?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I am used to Web MVC and I am now implementing it for the first time in Java and I am a bit confused as to what the View should observe, should it observe the individual entities or should it observe the service layer which obviously sit on top of the entities so when there is a change the service can notify the view and then my entities would not need to also be observable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your view should just be a representation of your objects and services. It should not have too much logic on it, just a way of representing your models. What framework are you using? As some encourage more some practices than others. If done correctly you could have two different views for example, displaying the same data but with a different presentation.

Comment: In MVC though doesn't the View observe the Model layer? I want to know does it observe the entities or your services? I'm not using any framework at the moment. I am trying to do a few basic things from scratch.

Comment: Your view shouldn't be observing anything, it should be used to represent your models and data from controllers. However, if what you mean is if your view should change if your models change, then the answer is yes, in most cases. In that case, I guess you can say your view is observing your models but only if that is what you mean.

Comment: If the view isn't observing the model layer how does it know/get notified that something has changed in the model layer and it needs to update itself?

Comment: @David The controller already knows about that change and updates the view.

Answer (score 0):

The view should only interact with a controller to prevent too much entanglement. The controller can be an observer of the view reacting to events happening inside the view and delegate it to the model layer. In no way should the view be able to modify/manipulate anything in the model layer. The view should be updated with data the controller provides. You shouldn't try to circumvent the controller and go directly to the model layer from inside the view. It might be tempting and seem logical, but at the end you will pay the price for it. Ending up with to much logic inside the view and the controller not having any real control at all.

Comment: The controllers job is to extract data and update the model layer but the view should have access to the model layer to retrieve its own data otherwise the view becomes dependent on the controller to get its data which was not the way MVC was designed. I used to have it where the controller would pass data to the view for a long time but I have since learned better.

Comment: @David It's far better to depend on a controller then to depend on the controller + the model layer. The view should not need to know where the data is coming from. If one would tie the view to the model layer it forces the view to know where the data comes from. Knowing the controller updates the model why would a view be responsible for updating itself when a model changes? The controller can just as easily push the update to the view.